# Delegators in ruby

Tags: ruby, delegates, delegation

I know there are three ways for delegate method call.

1. SimpleDelegator
2. Using DelegateClass
3. Using abstract class Delegator

I know what is delegation and how it works. I know how to delegate method call using SimpleDelegator. But I am not sure when will I use them. Can anyone give me some hint on when to use them. And how delegation is done using DelegateClass.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDelegator` is just a basic implementation of `Delegator`. `DelegateClass` is actually a method that defines delegator class. While `Delegator` delegates via `method_instance`, `DelegateClass` creates a new class that implements same API that superclass given to it.

So, when you don't need anything special, you would go with `SimpleDelegator`:

```
class AuthorDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def hi!
    "Hi, #{name}!"
  end
end

# assuming author is an object that responds to :name method
AuthorDecorator.new(author).hi! # => "Hi, Rohan!"
```

If you want to implement something more complex, e.g. you want have full control over `__setobj__` and `__getobj__` methods (for type coercion for example) you would go with `Delegator`.

As I said above, `DelegateClass` prepares a delegated class with predefined methods. Difference here is that when you use `SimpleDelegator` or `Delegator` it depends on `method_missing`, so if your delegator has no method that was requested, it will be proxied to delegated object via `method_missing`. In case of prepared base class with `DelegateClass` there will be already defined method that will call same method on delegated object. So `DelegateClass` provides a more efficient way to delegation.